# Getting a certain day from the current week then Query that date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Im trying to get the dates from Monday - Friday from the current week. then use those dates to query my mysql database. But my current code is not working.

```
$monday = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('next monday', strtotime('previous sunday')));
```

```
$sql = 
'SELECT *
FROM customers, jobs
WHERE customers.customerid = jobs.customerid AND duedate = "$monday" AND (jobs.status IS NULL OR jobs.status = "2" OR jobs.status = "3" OR jobs.status = "1" OR jobs.status = "5") AND (jobs.jobtype = "a" OR jobs.jobtype = "A" OR jobs.jobtype = "m" OR jobs.jobtype = "M")
ORDER BY duedate, jobtype';
```

I have Also tried use this code

```
$monday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'monday this week' ) );
```

Both ways it doesnt show any results.

Comment: TRY to check you SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dayoftweek()

for monday  = 2

```
    SELECT *
    FROM customers, jobs
    WHERE customers.customerid = jobs.customerid 
    AND DAYOFWEEK(duedate) =  2 
    AND (jobs.status IS NULL OR jobs.status = "2" 
        OR jobs.status = "3" 
        OR jobs.status = "1" 
        OR jobs.status = "5") 
    AND (jobs.jobtype = "a"
     OR jobs.jobtype = "A" 
     OR jobs.jobtype = "m" 
     OR jobs.jobtype = "M")
    ORDER BY duedate, jobtype
```

Comment: That works except it shows all of the jobs that are on a monday. I just want to show the monday for the current week.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Did it all in the sql query.

```
                        $sql = 
                        'SELECT *
                        FROM customers, jobs
                        WHERE customers.customerid = jobs.customerid AND DAYOFWEEK(duedate) =  3 AND YEARWEEK(duedate) = YEARWEEK(NOW())
                        AND (jobs.status IS NULL OR jobs.status = "2" OR jobs.status = "3" OR jobs.status = "1" OR jobs.status = "5") 
                        AND (jobs.jobtype = "a" OR jobs.jobtype = "A" OR jobs.jobtype = "m" OR jobs.jobtype = "M")
                        ORDER BY duedate, jobtype';
```